# Admin account locked out/redirect loop. Other accounts work?

Tags: wp-admin

my main admin account, admin is locked out of my website. If I log into it, I just get the "sorry you dont have permission to view this page" but if I log into one of my other admin accounts it's fine.

Any idea on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually figured out what was wrong.

Somehow my user permission was none. Then I change it to admin, still no luck...then realise it didn't change because there was no "nickname" set.

So basically just logged into another admin account and gave my account admin status.

Would love to know what caused it though.

Comment: Hard to know the cause without knowing if you have plugins that might affect 'user things'. Of if there is something in your functions.php file that might do the same. Of course, it's possible that there was some sort of attack on your site, which would be troublesome. 

So I'd inspect generated page source for anything unusual, and look at site files for something that shouldn't be there. When looking at files, sort by date to see if something is out of place. Look in all site folders.

Comment: Thanks appreciate the advice! I did some plugin updates the night before, so I'm pretty sure that's what has done it.